# hbm2ddl update option with script file in Spring boot

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have spring boot project which uses spring-data-jpa to connect a H2 db. I am also using hbm2ddl `update` option to create schema and entities which works well. My question is after application startup is it possible to run some script file for data insert purposes? 
Note:If I use `EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder` as data source and set script file, it expects schema and tables should be ready to insert data that is why I eliminated this option.

Comment: which script you wanted to run ? Is it SQL statements to be loaded to H2 db?

Comment: Yes, exactly. some insert statements.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `@component` bean (should be in scanned components class path) like below and use `@PostConstruct` to load the required data to H2 database.

```
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
    @Component
    public class H2ScriptLoader {

        @PostConstruct
        public void populateCache() {
            //code to load your script here
        }
    }
```